# Do vertex groups have a property like 'hide_render'?

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-groups

I want to make a video, where the points of a .ply pointcloud appear one after the other. I already made a script, where I placed a cube object at each desired point, joined it to the rest - I only want to see one "Face" object in my outliner - and made a vertex group representing the point.

I now wonder how I can first hide the whole object and than let all the vertex groups appear one at a time.

I would have expected something like the object's `.hide_render` function. And utilizing the mask modifier would require some extra thought as it is working the opposite way.